# How to use SharePoint only as a Content Management tool from a custom web application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, content-management

We have many custom built web applications (both external & internal) written in Classic ASP and ASP.NET 2.0 technologies. Internal users can upload files to these websites, which can then be viewed by External Users. In some cases, external users can upload documents as well. 
Screenshot #**1** gives a brief idea about the existing architecture.

1. Internal users upload documents to `custom web applications`. These documents are stored in a folder structure defined under the web application.
2. Meta data and user permissions like who can access the documents are stored in `SQL Server` database.
3. The same set of documents that are being uploaded to `custom web applications` also exist in `SharePoint`. However, the custom web applications are unaware of SharePoint. So, users have to download them from SharePoint and then Upload it to the custom web applications. We are currently using `SharePoint 2010`.
4. External users can also upload documents to the custom web applications. The meta data and user permissions of the document are saved into database based on the user who is uploading the document.

**Screenshot #1**:

[image: 1]

Screenshot #**2** shows the architecture that I am trying to achieve. I have done very little SharePoint development. Mostly, I have used the SharePoint web services to retrieve some list content but nothing more than that. Our future Custom Web Applications might be written using ASP.NET MVC. Please find the questions after the screenshot.

**Screenshot #2**:

[image: 2]

**Here are my questions:**

1. I would like to have `internal users` continue to upload and maintain their documents in SharePoint. User security model is already defined in the `SQL Server` database. This security permissions should be available in the SharePoint document properties so users can choose who can view the document from the custom web applications. How can I achieve this? Should I have to copy the SQL Server user permissions info to SharePoint?
2. I believe that `SharePoint Web Services` or `Business Connectivity Services (BCS)` can help in retrieving the document and its related info from SharePoint. Which one of these would better suit this scenario?
3. Custom web app should display only the committed versions of the documents. If a user has checked out a document in SharePoint to make any changes, that checked out version of the document should not be visible to External users. Is that possible?
4. Has anyone tried this approach? Are there any pitfalls with this model? Are there any performance concerns with this design?
5. Will this design be of any hindrance if I rewrite our existing applications using ASP.NET MVC?
6. Is it possible to make use of SharePoint search feature within the custom web application (`ASP.NET Web Forms` / `ASP.NET MVC`)? In other words, can I send search criteria from custom web app and have SharePoint do the search and return the results back to custom web app?

I really appreciate your inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: we discussed this during training sessions. The main question remained: Why spent 30.000 euro's to use only a very small part of the huge functionality of sharepoint, while there are many other cheaper tools that can handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1

Hard to say without having more details.  So I'm going to assume that you currently use Active Directory for your authentication store.  So this means that your SQL Server defines a list of roles and then has assigned memberships to these roles.  I'm going to assume that your assigned membership is to AD users or groups.  If this is true then I think your on the right path to push your permissions from SQL Server into SharePoint.  SharePoint's API will accommodate what you need to do, however SharePoint has no built into mechanism for syncing your permission changes so that means you end up writing a whole lot of plumbing code.  I would recommend that you research products that can handle the synchronization for you.  Microsoft MIIS (I believe it is called Forefront Identity Management now) offer a set of architecture patterns that you should investigate.

---

Question 2

SharePoint Web Services or the SharePoint Client Access Services should work fine.  I would highly recommend that use a proxy pattern to isolate your application from SharePoint calls (so you can isolate your application from SharePoint upgrades and potential content management server changes).

---

Question 3

Yes, that is possible.  If you are using the publishing features of SharePoint Server (NOT SharePoint Foundation) you will have an easy way of identifying the current published version.  Otherwise the service account you query with should be setup so it can only read published versions then SharePoint will automatically trim your query.

---

Question 4

I have not personally tried this design, but I really like the concept of creating a content management domain and then putting an abstract service layer on top of it.  Will you have scale problems, depends on how you configure SharePoint and your applications.  You can do it right or wrong.  An depth answer between the two cannot be covered here.  My one piece of advice is to make sure you plan for caching in your service interfaces (cache, cache, cache).

---

Question 5

Not if you implement it as a Service Layer.  You would just use a repository pattern to call the service and return back entities for your model.

---

Question 6

Yes, Search is exposed via an API so it can be wrapped in a service layer too.

---

Good luck and feel free to contact me directly for more in depth discussion.